# How to calculate torque for a linear slide pulley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

[image: slide]

I have a linear slide pulley system like in the picture (the string on the right will be attached to a spool, which is attached to a motor) and I'm trying to determine the right motor to buy to power the pulley so that I can lift a certain sized mass. How do I calculate the torque required for my application?